# Joining two list in one array in python

Tags: python, arrays, excel, list, arraylist

I want to join the column of an excel file to other 4 columns of another excel file.

Here's the code:

```
Array1 = []
Arraytest1 = []
Arraytest2 = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
    List1 = line.split('\t')[:4]
    List2 = line.split('\t')[10]
    Arraytest1.append(List1)
    Arraytest2.append(List2)
    Arraytest1.extend(Arraytest2)
    print 'Array 1   :', Arraytest1
```

What I see in output is :

> Array 1: [['A','B','C','D'],['E']]
>
> Array 1: [['A','B','C','D'],'E',['X1','X1','X1','X1'], 'E', Y1]

But what I what is something like:

> Array 1: ['A','B','C','D','E']
>
> Array 1: ['X1','X1','X1','X1','Y1']
>
> Array 1: ['X2','X2','X2','X2','Y2']

and so on..
I will appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List1 = line.split('\t')[:4]
```

makes `List1` a list already.

```
Arraytest1.append(List1)
```

is putting that list into ArrayTest1, think `ArrayTest1 = [[List1's contents]]`

Then when you are extending it, you are flatting it once but there's a nested list, that's why you see the results.

Try:

```
List1 = line.split('\t')[:4]
List2 = line.split('\t')[10]
Arraytest1.extend(List1)
Arraytest2.extend(List2)
Arraytest1.extend(Arraytest2)
print 'Array 1   :', Arraytest1
```

Or you can replace it with:

```
Arraytest1 += List1
Arraytest2 += List2
```

I'm sure you know but `append` adds the object to the list, `extend` adds each object in the iterable.

Append:

```
x = [1,2,3]
x.append([4,5])
#x is now [1,2,3,[4,5]]
```

Extend

```
x = [1,2,3]
x.append([4,5])
#x is now [1,2,3,4,5]
x.append(1) #throws error
```

Split returns a list... but sometimes if you just want to split a string just cast it.

```
x = "hello"
x = x.split()
#x is now ['hello']

x = "hello"
x = list(x)
#x is now ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Splitting sentences is what split usually do, Strings in Python are iterables so you can just cast them into list to split them up into each characters. I think that's what you want'

Edited: Based on your comments it's a for loop issue:

You are appending adding to the list as the for loop goes, but it seems like you want a new list everytime it loops. You aren't replacing the list with a clean one and you just appending to it everytime. try replacing:

```
Arraytest1.extend(List1)
Arraytest2.extend(List2)
```

Too:

```
Arraytest1 = List1[:]
Arraytest2 = List2[:]
```

Comment: Thanks, but whenever I replaced `'E'` with `'Test'` in output Instead of `'Test'` I see something like `'T '`, `'E '`, `'S '`, `'T '`

Comment: Was editing my answer to include that sorry forgot it xD take a look

Comment: A , B ,C, D and E in my real code are names and I used split cause I'm reading them from a txt file. This txt file consists of different columns which are separated by  a tab

Comment: @Braian I think I found your issue see edited question

Comment: It works very well just remains `'Test'` as the element of new column which separates like `'T '`, `'E '`, `'S '`, `'T '`

Comment: Thanks, now it works, I changed `line.split('\t')[10]` to `line.split('\t')[10:11]`